# Can I use dotnet test --filter to run all default tests plus a specified Category?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, nunit

I'd like to configure my dotnet core nUnit tests to disable integration tests by default, allowing all non-integration tests to run "by default", and in CI also add-in the integration tests.  It's important that I don't have to decorate the "default" unit tests--so that there's no chance of forgetting to tag them correctly, leading to them not running when expected.

So far I've been trying to mark the Integration tests by decorating them with `[Explicit, Category("Integration")]`, like:

```
[TestFixture, Explicit, Category("Integration")]
public class IntegrationTests {...}

[TestFixture]
public class UnitTests {...}
```

With that setup `dotnet test` works as expected--tests in `UnitTests` are ran, and `IntegrationTests` are skipped.

But, I'm having a hard time passing a `--filter` argument to run BOTH the defaults, and the Integration tests.  Running `dotnet test --filter TestCategory=Integration` runs *only* the Integration tests.

The best I've been able to do is to combine a `FullyQualifiedName~Test` (my namespaces start with `Test`) -- `dotnet test --filter "TestCategory=Integration|FullyQualifiedName~Test"`.

That works, but leaves the small chance that (for no good reason) someone uses a different root namespace.

(fyi: I'm using `NUnit 3.12.0` and `NUnit3TestAdapter 4.0.0-beta.2` to avoid [known issues with filters](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/473#issuecomment-658174038) in 3.17.0 and below)

Comment: Assuming all tests start with "Test" I'd expect your workaround filter expression to run __all__ tests, including those in SomeOtherCategory.

Comment: Good point!  The result is the same as `--filter "FullyQualifiedName~Test"` -- not what I want :-(

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, the ability to select tests with no category specified has been discussed as an enhancement to NUnit, but it hasn't been implemented as far as I know.

The only workaround I can think of is to add a category to all the tests, which do not have one already. You could call it "Default" or "Always" or "None" or anything else you like. Then, when running, specify `TestCategory="Integration"|TestCategory="None"`.

The obvious drawback is that you have to add an attribute to every test and then maintain it as new categories are added.

Comment: Thanks; glad to hear I'm not overlooking something dead-simple!  I'll leave the question open a while longer in hopes of a little more input, but expect you're correct.  My team has been discussion just running `dotnet test` twice--once for the defaults, again for the integration tests, although reporting might suffer